# Send data to WebAPI (C#) GET Request Ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to use html to  get WebApi ReturnValue. (type：Get、datatype：Jsonp)

Now when I direct execution WebApi, it can get ReturnValue "2" (indicate execution  Success).

But when via by html + Jquery + ajax , it always show error function information.
[image]

How an I resolve this problem, thanks.

------------- code -------------

API Model：

```
 public class LoginModel
    {
        public int Userno { get; set; }
        public List<Second> LoginSecond { get; set; }
    }
    public class Second
    {
        public string testinfo01 { get; set; }
        public string testinfo02 { get; set; }
        public List<Third> Third { get; set; }
    }

    public class Third
    {
        public string finValue { get; set; }
    }
```

API Controller：

```
 [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string id, string id1) //id=Account，id1=password
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testconn"].ConnectionString;
        string Dictionary = Login.Login(id, id1).ToString();
        return Dictionary;
    }
```

Html：

```
<div class="form" id="form"> 
    <form class="login-form" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="inpAcc" placeholder="Acc"/>
    <input type="password" id="inpPwd" placeholder="pwd"/>
    <input id="loginbtn" type="button" value="login"></input>
    <input id="data" type="label" />
  </form>
</div>
```

jquery + ajax：

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('click', '#loginbtn',function(){
                var username = $("input#inpAcc").val();
                var password = $("input#inpPwd").val(); 
                alert(username);
                var APIurl = "localhost:10733/Api/Login/";
              $.ajax({
                  type: "get",
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  username:username,
                  password:password,
                  url: APIurl +"/"+username+"/"+password,
                  async: false,
                  headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

               data :function (data)
               {
                var returnvalue = data[0].request();
                console.log(data.stat);
                console.log(data.status);
                console.log(data.message);
                console.log(data.html);
                alert(returnvalue);
               },
              error: function(request, status, error) {

                console.log(request.stat);
                console.log(request.status);
                console.log(request.message);
                console.log(request.html);
                alert(request.responseText);
              },
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.stat);
                console.log(data.status);
                console.log(data.message);
                console.log(data.html);
                alert(data);
              }
          });        
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you declared route for this? if you didn't declared route for this. I prefer you to pas data with parameter name like  APIurl +"?id="+username+"&id1="+password

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham I fix route for this project
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id1}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id1 = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham but it always have same error.

Comment: You have a extra "/" so remove it url: APIurl +username+"/"+password,

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham HI，I try to use your way, it have erroe message.
error message：
http://XXXXX/Api/LoginACCOUNTPASSWORD?callback=jQuery31107084836663417862_1484102732898&_=1484102732899 

And state is ：404

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham 
HI,I use this url  url: APIurl +username+"/"+password,

but Have same message

Comment: http://ZZZZ/Api/LoginACCOUNT/PASSWORD?callback=jQuery31107942508263066868_1484103354679&_=1484103354680 
 state is ：404

Comment: SO I think url will be  url: APIurl +username +"/"+password,

Comment: Please check my answer. Its working on my local, So it will work for you. Remove route configurations if have any related to it

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham HI 
HI：I try to use your way , but it can not get return value，error is jquery. and url have callback value.
 
I use jquery-1.9.1.min.js , can I ask you which version you use it ?

error picture ：http://ppt.cc/gfFKJ

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham
HI ：

I put Web API to IIS , and port is 80
But have error message - have callbackvalue as this picture ： http://ppt.cc/kbXPN

state is 200 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your source. Remove the route configuration as below source included route config inline.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get/{id}/{id1?}")]
    public string Get(string id, string id1 = null) //id=Account，id1=password
    {
        return "Working";
    }
}
```

to call above api your url should be like

```
http://localhost:11299/api/login/Get/id/id1/
```

In the above id1 is optional

Comment: HI：I use "url: APIurl +username+"/"+password"
ERROR MESSAGE：
http://XXXX/Api/LoginACCOUNT/PASSWORD?callback=jQuery31107345746889901397_1484102961300&_=1484102961301 

SO I think ""url: APIurl +"/" +username+"/"+password""

Comment: HI：I try to use your way , 
but it can not get return value，error is jquery.

Comment: I use jquery-1.9.1.min.js , can I ask you which version you use it ?

Comment: Does it hitting to server? did you placed debugger on server side and tested it? try to access the url directly from your browser, If it work from browser then it should work from url ajax request another thing is does web api hosted in different server or port?

Comment: HI ：
I put Web API to IIS , and port is 80
But have error message - have callbackvalue as this picture ： http://ppt.cc/kbXPN

Comment: I am checking it will let you know